# Inner parameters are not updated in the nested optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a problem with nested optimization. In my program, I select one from the list `minipotentX` that can maximize the value of the function `pieRestMini`. Then, I use this selected one as one of the inputs of another function `piPlatMini`. Parameters `\[Theta]` and `m` are the inputs for the function `optMiniX` and the `piPlatMini`. The code is as follows:

```
fOne[q_] := 
  Piecewise[{{q*1/15, 0 \[LessSlantEqual] q < 3}, {1/5 - (q - 3)*1/35,
      3 \[LessSlantEqual] q \[LessSlantEqual] 10}}, 0];

lambdaTwo[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(4*(1 - 
           4/45*Integrate[q*fOne[q], {q, x, 10}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 10]) - 4/45*Integrate[q^2*fOne[q], {q, x, 10}, 
          Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 10])*6/295, 
     0 \[LessSlantEqual] x < 4.18}, {6/235, 4.18 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 
      6.83}, {(2*1*(1 - 4/45*Integrate[q*fOne[q], {q, x, 10}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 
               0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 10]) - 4/45*Integrate[q^2*fOne[q], {q, x, 10}, 
          Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 10])*6/235, 
     6.83 < x \[LessSlantEqual] 10}}, 0];

Remove[optMiniX]
optMiniX[\[Theta]_, m_] := 
  Module[{minipotentX, xFive, xSix, optconsX, pieRestMini},
   pieRestMini[x_] := lambdaTwo[x]*5 + 4/45*Integrate[(q - Max[\[Theta]*q, m])*fOne[q], {q, x, 10}, 
       Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && 0 \[LessSlantEqual] x \[LessSlantEqual] 10];
   xFive = Values[Solve[x^2 - x*35/6 + 4*m + m*35/6 == 0, x][[1]][[1]]];
   xSix = Values[Solve[x^2 - x*35/6 + 2*m + m*35/6 == 0, x][[1]][[1]]];
   minipotentX = Select[{xFive, 4.18, xSix, 6.83, 10, m}, # \[Element] Reals &];
   optconsX = minipotentX[[Ordering[Table[pieRestMini[i], {i, minipotentX}], -1][[1]]]];
   optconsX
   ];

piPlatMini[y_, \[Theta]_ /; NumberQ[\[Theta]], m_ /; NumberQ[m]] := 
  4/45*Integrate[(Max[\[Theta]*q, m] + 1/5)*fOne[q], {q, y, 10}, 
    Assumptions -> y \[Element] Reals && 0 \[LessSlantEqual] y \[LessSlantEqual] 10 && 
      m \[Element] Reals &&  0 \[LessSlantEqual] m \[LessSlantEqual] 10 && 0 <= \[Theta] <= 1 && \[Theta] \[Element] Reals];
```

The problem occurs in the maximization process. When I directly do the nested maximization,

```
re=NMaximize[{piPlatMini[optMiniX[\[Theta], m], \[Theta], m], \[Theta] \[Element] Reals && 0 <= \[Theta] < 1 && m \[Element] Reals && 0 <= m < 10}, {\[Theta], m}]
```

the result is as follows:

```
{0.130157, {\[Theta] -> 0.999933, m -> 10.}}
```

When I directly put the optimal solution into the function `optMiniX`:

```
optMiniX[\[Theta], m]/. re[[2]]
```

the result is different

```
Root[78825 - 3760 #^2 - 376 #^3 + 47 #^4& , 1, 0]
```

But the analytical result should be `10`!

I think Mathematica only updates `\[Theta]` and `m` in the outer function and doesn't update `\[Theta]` and `m` in the inner function. The folloing evidence is got when I use `Maximize` function:

In

```
Maximize[{piPlatMini[optMiniX[\[Theta], m], \[Theta], 
   m], \[Theta] \[Element] Reals && 0 <= \[Theta] <= 1 && 
   m \[Element] Reals && 0 <= m <= 10}, {\[Theta], m}]
```

Out

```
Maximize[{piPlatMini[Root[
   78825 - 3760 #^2 - 376 #^3 + 47 #^4& , 1, 0], \[Theta], 
   m], \[Theta] \[Element] Reals && 0 <= \[Theta] <= 1 && 
   m \[Element] Reals && 0 <= m <= 10}, {\[Theta], m}]
```

I wonder how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output that is printed on the screen is abbreviated. You must use all digits of the answer. E,g.:re = NMaximize[{piPlatMini[optMiniX[θ, m], θ, 
     m], θ ∈ Reals && 0 <= θ < 1 && 
     m ∈ Reals && 0 <= m < 10}, {θ, m}];
piPlatMini[optMiniX[θ, m], θ, m] /. re[[2]]
 then you get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have revised the code according to your advice. But I still find that the result is not correct. The value of optMiniX under the solution is not correct. And when I use Maximize function, the value of theta and m in the function is fixed.